# Review flag does not indicate items to review

Tags: support, review

I notice that now there seems to be a rust colored flag between my usercard and "review" in the top bar.  As I type this, it reads `4`.  Clicking on it takes me to the review queue where there are... **0** items to be reviewed.  Does anyone know what is the deal is?

Comment: I've noticed the same, just in the last day or thereabouts. In the past the flag has indicated items in the "Suggested Edit" queue, but none appear there, and even after clearing other queues, it's still there, which wasn't happening before.

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230874/bring-back-the-suggested-edits-notifications-to-the-top-bar-again) seems to be relevant. I'm not sure I get everything in that account though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've submitted [my own feature request regarding this notification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230833/246931). Its functionality was changed recently to display the number of flags available for review to the community as a whole for users who have unlocked the moderation tools privilege (see [Anna Lear's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230726/246931) to "[Notify users of possible reviews on toolbar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191638/246931)"). This does not exclude flags you've already reviewed, as [Shog9 says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191638/notify-users-of-possible-reviews-on-toolbar?lq=1#comment758002_230726) that degree of personalization would be too expensive for the developers. For those of us without moderation tools unlocked, the old suggested edits notification works like it used to. I've requested that this old notification continue to take priority over the new notification, or that the new notification respond somehow to our clicks or to changes in the number of active flags. I would appreciate any support or feedback that the CV community can offer me on this. That feature request once again is: "[Modulate the review notification's color to reflect changes, or make it dismissible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230833/246931)".

Note that snailplane's feature request "[Bring back the suggested edits notifications to the top bar . . . again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230874/246931)" has been marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), so further fulfillment of the true intent of that request is not likely forthcoming (unless, hopefully, the old notification can take priority over the new notification without deactivating it, as I've requested). As I implied in [my comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230874/bring-back-the-suggested-edits-notifications-to-the-top-bar-again#comment758460_230874), that was probably a foregone conclusion of that feature request. The new notification functionality [is favored because it seems to help clear review queues for the community as a whole](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191638/notify-users-of-possible-reviews-on-toolbar?lq=1#comment757998_230726). As I've [quoted Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191638/notify-users-of-possible-reviews-on-toolbar?lq=1#comment758002_230726) in my feature request, it is supposed to compel us to encourage each other to review after we've done as much as we can personally. IMO, it's presently too confusing to lead naturally to that, and it should have its design modified somehow to disambiguate it from the suggested edits notifications that old users are accustomed to, and that new users will see until they unlock the moderation tools privilege, which [does not yet mention the change in notification functionality that comes with the privilege](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

Comment: As it stands, it conveys no useful information to me at all (while the old one did contain highly relevant information). I really liked the old one, since edits, at least, were noticed really fast. I'd rather *switch it off altogether* than have it behave like it does now.

Comment: I can relate, but I get the feeling that highly active users who are on top of the review queue anyway are expected to accept this change for the good of the community. Yeah, your notification is probably less useful for you now, but the users who don't pay that much attention to reviews are now more likely to have a notification and do their part too. At least, I assume that's why review queues were emptying when Shog9 checked them; maybe this explanation is debatable.

Comment: Review queues are empty here because the high reputation users work very hard to keep them empty (several users are much more diligent than me, & contribute a lot to making the site work so well). I'm not sure that making that job harder in the *hope* that it might improve things long term is going to avoid *longer* queues. To me it seems a little premature, at least without getting some buy-in from the people bearing the load. It's not hard to see who is doing the reviewing on the various queues, so we should be able to see if there's been a clear increase in new people since the change.

Comment: I get the feeling that the change was aimed at short-term improvements on other sites, and that it was somewhat insensitive to per-site differences in review issues.
Arguably, the new notification is more like a "finger on the pulse" of the community than the personal notifications we're used to. Maybe with time some uses for that information will become apparent, like organizing queue-clearing rallies...but I think that requires people to understand and embrace the new notification. Understanding and acceptance have been a little deficient so far (needless to say), and for good reasons.

Comment: I also upvoted your meta.SE request.